# Why is index giving a completely wrong output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

Normally I use index to find the index of an element in a list. I made this really basic program but it's not showing the output as I expected. This is my code:

```
store_1 = []
for i in range(8):
    mountain_height = int(input())
    store_1.append(mountain_height)
    print(store_1.index(store_1[-1]))
```

Result:

```
    0
   [0]
   Index: 0
   0
   [0, 0]
   Index: 0
   0
   [0, 0, 0]
   Index: 0
   0
   [0, 0, 0, 0]
   Index: 0
   6
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
   Index: 4
   5
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5]
   Index: 5
   2
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 2]
   Index: 6
   4
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 2, 4]
   Index: 7
```

As you can see the element 1, element 2 and element 3 are giving the wrong index, it's indexes should be 1, 2, 3. I am trying to get the index of the very last element added in the list.

Why is this happening and how can i solve this problem?

Comment: **index()** method on list always prints the index of first matching element in the list. So that's why you are getting same output 0 in those 3 cases.

Comment: How is python supposed to know which one of the 4 zeros you were looking for? It just returns the index of the first one.

Comment: @Aran-Fey but i indicated it, the [-1]

Comment: 0 is 0, no matter how it's obtained. There's no difference between the 0 at `store[-1]` and the 0 at `store[-2]` or `store[-3]` or `store[-4]`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Thanks I get it, but is there a way around it?

Comment: Yes, use `i` instead of `store_1.index(store_1[-1])`. Or `len(store_1) - 1`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks, it solved it!

Comment: Why are you even using `.index` when you already know the index of the current item? BTW, `.index` is rather slow because it has to do a linear scan from the start of the list until it finds the 1st matching item, so it's best to avoid it unless you have no alternative.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**@mahir**, you can use the below code to get your output.

> **index()** method on list always prints the index of first matching element in the list. So that's why you are getting same output 0 in those 3 cases.

You may see the information related to the **index()** method on list as shown below.

```
>>> help(list.index)
Help on method_descriptor:

index(...)
    L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

>>>
```

#### Source code:

```
store_1 = []

for i in range(8):
    mountain_height = int(input())
    store_1.append(mountain_height)
    last_index = store_1.index(store_1[-1], -1)
    print('Index:', last_index)
    print(store_1)
```

#### Output:

```
$ python PythonEnumerate.py
0
Index: 0
[0]
0
Index: 1
[0, 0]
0
Index: 2
[0, 0, 0]
0
Index: 3
[0, 0, 0, 0]
6
Index: 4
[0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
5
Index: 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5]
4
Index: 6
[0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 4]
2
Index: 7
[0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

index() returns the **first** element of a list of the specific value.

So, for a list like yours : [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 2, 4]
list.index(0) is always going to return 0, no matter what, because the first 0 is at liste[0].

Another example, for a list like this one : [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
liste.index(2) is always going to return 1 and never 3. Because the first '2' is at the index 1.

If you want to distinguish between the different 0 in your list, I suggest using the value of i.

Hope it helps.